# Trouble importing a mysql database table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Today I am trying to move my servers, and one step into that process is to move my mysql servers.

So first I went to the old database table and used the phpmyadmin export option to get a table.sql file as seen here:
[image]

Next, using a sftp client I dropped the .sql file onto the new server. I installed mysql & phpmyadmin on the new server.

The .sql is quite large (>2MB) so I am not going to bother using phpmyadmins import option.

Doing some research on stack over flow the command to import the table is:

```
mysql -u root -p database_name < table_name.sql
```

I used this countless times successfully, so I am not sure why it is failing this time.

On the new server, I created a empty database named FlareHub:
[image]

Then executed: `mysql -u root -p FlareHub < FlareHub_Auth.sql`

Terminal asked for my password, and I clicked enter.

I refreshed the phpmyadmin page.. it got imported but I have no idea what happened because it is not usable..:
[image]

I think I am missing something obvious but have no idea what is wrong. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message in phpMyAdmin, it is not able to connect to and authenticate against the database server. Make sure that your username, password, and host are set correctly.